# Can call stack run out of memory?

Tags: memory, haskell, memory-management, recursion, callstack

A question arised when I was programming a recursive function in Haskell;  Can any call stack in any language (or just Haskell) run out of memory at a particular point?

Thanks :)

Comment: The name of this very website may be instructive.

Comment: I found this question very ironic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a finite amount of memory, and if each frame on the call stack takes a non-zero number of bytes (tail-call optimization makes this a little more complex), you *must* be able to exhaust the resource with a deep enough recursion. Basic logic.

That said, how deep you can go does depend on the implementation of the stack. Where the stack is implemented in the normal interrupt stack (also called the C stack due to its association with that language), you have quite a limited space available, enough to get pretty deep with small frames but really limited when the frame size goes up (with more variables of larger types). Not all languages use the interrupt stack, instead locating their stacks in heap space (much larger).

Answer (score 2):

Usually stack size is not an issue in Haskell implementations as it is in C, since it is a functional language with a non-standard virtual machine, i.e. its function calls are not mapped directly to process stack frames; they are managed and can be allocated on heap (something like Stackless Python). But the size is finite and can give you a stack overflow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. It depends on the resources allocated for the stack for that particular program, but if it is too eager, it will eventually end in a stack overflow. You'll find more infos and examples on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The stack is just a region of memory and as such is a finite resource and can run out if you abuse it. In C++ this does not just apply to recursion, but creation of too many or (or too large) variables on the stack instead of the heap.